# How to determine if a date it was yesterday, in the last month, in the last year using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I would like to determine if a DateTime was yesterday, if it was in the last month and if it was in the last year.

For example if today is 2013. 10. 21. then 2013. 10. 20. was yesterday, 2013. 09. 23. was in the last month and 2012. 03. 25. was in the last year.

How can i determine these using c#?

Comment: are you trying to create something like a relative representation like '3 days and 4 hours ago' ?

Comment: No, I don't. I just have to get the rows from a database table based on the time added: the rows added yesterday, in the last month, and in the last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool IsYesterday(DateTime dt)
{
    DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    if (dt >= yesterday && dt < DateTime.Today)
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool IsInLastMonth(DateTime dt)
{
    DateTime lastMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
    return dt.Month == lastMonth.Month && dt.Year == lastMonth.Year;
}

bool IsInLastYear(DateTime dt)
{
    return dt.Year == DateTime.Now.Year - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// myDate = 2012.02.14 ToDate ... you know 

if (myDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);)
    Console.WriteLine("Yestoday");

else if (myDate > DateTime.Today.AddMonth(-1) && myDate < DateTime.Today)
   Console.WriteLine("Last month");

// and so on
```

it needs test and fixes, but it is the way ;)

Comment: If today is 2013. 10. 21. and I test 2013. 10. 15. then it tells me "Last month", but it was this month.

Comment: As i said, it needs testing, but the mechanism is that.
Amúgy Szia Szabolcs ;)

Comment: The example above it works, but thank you anyway. :) Köszönöm!

Answer (score 1):

I think testing like this could do the trick:

`if(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(-1) > dateToTestIfLastMonth){`

Comment: Yes, but I don't program C# too often, so I don't know the capitalization by heart. Sorry, but do feel free to edit it...

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx

You can subtract dates then check the timespan object.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward implementation:

```
public enum DateReference {
    Unknown,
    Yesterday,
    LastMonth,
    LastYear,
}

public static DateReference GetDateReference(DateTime dateTime) {
    var date = dateTime.Date;
    var dateNow = DateTime.Today;

    bool isLastYear = date.Year == dateNow.Year - 1;
    bool isThisYear = date.Year == dateNow.Year;
    bool isLastMonth = date.Month == dateNow.Month - 1;
    bool isThisMonth = date.Month == dateNow.Month;
    bool isLastDay = date.Day == dateNow.Day - 1;

    if (isLastYear)
        return DateReference.LastYear;
    else if (isThisYear && isLastMonth)
        return DateReference.LastMonth;
    else if (isThisYear && isThisMonth && isLastDay)
        return DateReference.Yesterday;

    return DateReference.Unknown;
}
```